# which ever android app i am running is getting forced close error kindly help me my code for this is

Tags: android

I get a problem whenever I try to run any Android app. I have downloaded Eclipse indigo and its ADT plugin also which is version: 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.

`MainActivity.java`:

```java
package com.example.onlineres;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class  MainActivity extends ListActivity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
 try{
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/city.php");
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 is = entity.getContent();
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
}
 //convert response to string
  try{
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader                             
 (is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
   sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

   String line="0";
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
 //paring data
 int ct_id;
String ct_name;
 try{
  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  JSONObject json_data=null;
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         ct_id=json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
         ct_name=json_data.getString("CITY_NAME");
     }
  }
  catch(JSONException e1){
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

`manifest.xml`: (I have added use permission to access Internet)

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.onlineres"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The logcat is

```
07-19 14:08:04.933: W/ActivityThread(271): Application com.example.onlineres is             waiting     for the debugger on port 8100...
07-19 14:08:04.963: I/System.out(271): Sending WAIT chunk
07-19 14:08:05.023: I/dalvikvm(271): Debugger is active
07-19 14:08:05.173: I/System.out(271): Debugger has connected
07-19 14:08:05.173: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:05.373: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:05.573: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:05.776: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:05.981: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:06.183: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:06.383: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:06.586: I/System.out(271): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-19 14:08:06.793: I/System.out(271): debugger has settled (1348)
07-19 14:08:45.853: D/AndroidRuntime(271): Shutting down VM
07-19 14:08:45.853: W/dalvikvm(271): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x4001d800)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.onlineres/com.example.onlineres.MainActivity}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.example.onlineres.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-19 14:08:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You'll need to add whatever is in logcat after the debugger settle messages.

Comment: Not clear what error is, but you should put network connect code in thread.

Comment: log cat complete code is

Comment: @Dya how can i add complete logcat here its not allowing tell me ur email id

Comment: Edit your question to add the logcat, use the `{}` button, review the question to check it shows

Comment: @dya it will take much time to format all the code can u tell me some shortcut

Comment: @Geoff i have added log cat now can u help me

Answer (score 1):

If your error is the debugger : try to add this attribute in Manifest.xml :

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

else, try to launch your application in normal mode and post your error stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

**> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'** - This is one of the errors in your logcat.

Change the id of the listView to take  `android:id="@android:id/list"`